# Problem installing Bluetooth Dongle on Raspberry Pi 2 running Windows 10 IOT Core

Tags: bluetooth, windows-iot, peripherals

I recently got an Orico BTA-403 (officially supported) bluetooth dongle and inserted it into my Raspberry Pi 2, Model B running the most recent version of Windows 10 IOT core.  I rebooted, and then...

Nothing happened - no devices are there (there should be several) and no indication that the dongle is present.

Is there some step I'm missing?

[image: My bluetooth screen]

Comment: Can you see the Windows IoT Bluetooth from any other device, like a smart phone? There are no extra steps. It is just plug and pray.  Double check the dongle works on a Windows PC (It should just work without driver installation on Windows 7+) I used a generic 3$ Bluetooth and it just worked straight away.(lucky it was a supported chip, but what I mean there are no extra steps)

Comment: Nope - it does not show up at all - I will test with a regular pc

Comment: It works just fine with a regular pc.

Comment: Maybe not enough power on the Pi? It may blink but it just be browning out.